# Wordpress - Query to fetch all unattached media

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to do a SQL query to select all unattached media.
I tried this following query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p1 ON p.post_parent = p1.ID
WHERE p.post_parent > 0 AND p.post_type = 'attachment' AND p1.ID IS NULL;
```

The problem is that this query doesn't fetch **all** the unattached media...
Do you have a better query?

Thank you

EDIT

Here is my new try (without more success):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
WHERE p.post_mime_type IN ("image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg")
AND p.post_type = 'attachment' 
AND pm.meta_key IN ('_product_image_gallery', '_thumbnail_id')
AND pm.meta_value NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', p.ID ,'%')
```

Comment: The best thing to do is to find an unattached record that isn't returned by this query - I assume you have examples? - and try and work out why not. e.g. is it because p.post_parent == 0 or IS NULL? Then work that into your query.

Comment: Still not ... :(

Comment: OK. Can you show us an example of some unattached media that isn't returned by this query?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbed on similar problem and couldn§t find any solution, answered similar question in [Wordpress get attachment of post doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627394/wordpress-get-attachment-of-post-doesnt-work/58451936#58451936) hope it will help.

Comment: Hi there, why not? it fetches all post attachements attached or unatachhed, you just have to know your field names.

Comment: I think it juste get attachments for a product